# php fsockopen() cannot make connection

Tags: php, port, fsockopen

I have a problem about fsockopen().

when i write code from http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android it doesn't work, and i get:

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to localhost:port
(No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpMQTTClient-master\SAM\MQTT\sam_mqtt.php on line 641
Offline
```

I have try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/ce22ef1c-72ac-47da-afd7-5ec7a5ffd6bb/), but it cannot solve my problem.
Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Check for the port. Is it open or not?

Comment: user2484675, is there Server running on destination host you are trying to connect?

Comment: thanks @Goutam Pal, i have check the port and found it closed. i change the port to open port.

Answer (score 2):

This function [`fsockopen("www.example.com", 80)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) returns a stream `resource` if the connection is successful.

However, if the connection fails it will generate an error as you receive:

You can use [`@ operator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to silence the error

```
$resource = @fsockopen("127.0.0.1","882");
// $resource will be stream resource object if call is successful
// $resource will be false if call  fails
```

to avoid raising and error and get `false` as the return value when connection fails.

Comment: Obviously, adding `@` will not make the connection successful but only allow your own code to handle the failure. The failure in original question is probably caused by too eager firewall settings.